# Is there a way I can play a sound resource (MediaPlayer) more than once at the same time from the same instance?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

Or do I constantly have to reinstantiate it?

I have a sound file that plays an explosion every time a ship blows up, but sometimes three or more ships can blow up at the same time, so I want the same sound clip to overlap.  I notice it won't do that unless I create new instances.  Is there something I'm missing or is that the only way to do it?

```
//declaration
private final MediaPlayer[] explosionSound = new MediaPlayer[5];

//constructor
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    explosionSound[i] = MediaPlayer.create(app, R.raw.explosion);
}

//in program where I want to use it (when I want to play the sound)
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (!explosionSound[i].isPlaying())
    {
        explosionSound[i].start();
        break;
    }
}

//onDestroy() method to release the media
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    explosionSound[i].release();
}
```

I tried to instantiate a new one anonymously but it complained about it not being released (the error goes away when you release it in the onDestroy() method).  I can't release it right away or else the sound doesn't play at all.  I don't want to limit myself to 5 explosions either.  Now I'm worried about memory issues too.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer is not really meant to solve the problem of small, overlapping audio clips.  It's more for long-running media, both audio and video.

A better tool for your particular situation is [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), which is specifically designed for your case.

Comment: I notice to use SoundPool, I also have to use AudioAttributes, which requires API 21.  Right now, with MediaPlayer, my min API of 8 works.  Is SoundPool the only option that requires API 21 or higher?  I want my app to work on older phones as well.

Comment: All methods of SoundPool are available since API level 8, most from earlier.  You can see that for yourself in the docs I linked to.